# Meteor deployment issue : module did not self-register

Tags: linux, node.js, meteor, deployment

I just rented a small sever at digitalocean and then I followed this tutorial to install meteor :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx

I understood what I did and everything went well.
Then when I first started the project, I got a nodejs version issue so I updated it to  4.... 
Then I got a fibers issue so I reinstalled it and now I get this :

Upstart log :

> /home/[user]/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
>                                                   throw(ex);
>                                                         ^ Error: Module did not self-register.
>       at Error (native)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at bindings (/home/[user]/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
>       at Object. (/home/[user]/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)

First I tried to downgrade to nodejs 0.12 because that is what I use in development. I also tried to delete the node_module folder and npm reinstall/rebuild everything. And I just tried to reinstall bcrypt

I'm stuck and I am not sure what is the actual issue.

What should I do ?

rXp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix this error with :

```
cd /home/*your_app_name*/app/programs/server/npm/mode_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt
npm install bcrypt
```

But now I don't have any error in upstart or the app and everything is running BUT I still get an error 503 on http and an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on https.

Why ? It should work now

Answer (score 1):

I found a lot of solutions to the problem, it solved me totally the error:

```
cd /home/$YOUR_APP/bundle/programs/server/
npm install
npm rebuild
cd npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt
npm install bcrypt
```

And specifying the architecture can help too:

```
meteor build . --architecture os.linux.x86_64
```

here you can read about it: [Solution to Meteor deploy conflict with bcrypt](https://medium.com/@akosb/solution-to-meteor-deploy-conflict-with-bcrypt-cd3596984350#.vab55a32o)